# What is `run-init` actually?

Tags: initramfs

There's an `init` script in the initial ramdisk during the bootint process.
At the last operation, it says that:

```
# Chain to real filesystem
exec run-init ${rootmnt} ${init} "$@" ${recovery:+--startup-event=recovery} <${rootmnt}/dev/console >${rootmnt}/dev/console 2>&1
panic "Could not execute run-init."
```

I search all scripts in ramdisk content, and can't find any file name or function name like that.What is the `run-init` actually?

Comment: see this: http://linux.die.net/man/8/run_init

Comment: I visit that link already. But it says that script(I guess) is in SELinux, I can't find it in Ubuntu. Where is it? Or it doesn't existed in Ubuntu?

Comment: for me it is in `/usr/lib/klibc/bin/run-init`. use `locate run-init` to find it in your system.

Comment: OK, I found it,too.
But `panic` is next line after the `exec run-init...`, is that mean the flow or control right will migrated to ${rootmnt}? If not so, we'll going to crash by next `panic`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`run-init` is a binary executable, it lives in /usr/lib/klibc/bin/run-init **and in your initramfs** and is provided by the `klibc-utils` package in Ubuntu. It isn't a script, so you cannot take a look inside directly, you can check out its source code via running `apt source klibc-utils` or browsing the upstream repository at https://git.kernel.org/cgit/libs/klibc/klibc.git.

So the main function is in [run-init.c](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/klibc/klibc.git/tree/usr/kinit/run-init/run-init.c) , but it's just a wrapper for `run_init` function, which lives here in [runinitlib.c](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/klibc/klibc.git/tree/usr/kinit/run-init/runinitlib.c)

`run_init` does a lot of work:

1. It jumps into the new root file system
2. Checks that this is the new root file system
3. Checks if it on initramfs
4. Cleans all directory (why waste the RAM?)
5. Mounts the new root file system
6. and runs init in the new root file system

I believe, it would be very complicated to do all this work by a script, because of dependencies, but binary executable file can do it very ease.

Comment: It chroots to the new root file system, it has toi be mounted before running it.

Answer (score 1):

According to `dpkg-query` it's part of the `klibc-utils` package. Some digging in the source code shows a call to `execv` to start the init process on the real filesystem. If that fails, `run-init` will return, thus triggering the `panic` on the last line.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 14.04LTS
In empty folder create file [get-it.sh]

```
#!/bin/sh

cp /boot/initrd* initrd.cpio.gz
mkdir initrd
cd initrd
zcat ../initrd.cpio.gz | cpio -di
find | grep run-init
cd ..
```

and run it: bash get-it.sh

file run-init will be in ./bin/run-init

Also you can get initrd from installation cd